You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested
I am facing the following error while updating account on contact, it sounds weird to me as the logged in user has modify all access on permission set on both account and contact objects. Its coming only when logged-in user only updating account on contact and for other fields excluding account, update works fine without issues.
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.


As per this reference, it is mentioned that, permission set needs to have permission to Run Flow or Manage Flows, I provided the same, still same issue. The basic permissions look perfect to me like object level, record level.
Am I missing anything here? any special cases related to account update on contact? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Are there any validation rule in Contact object?

Can you check on these [sharing on object, owd, role hirarchy, manual sharing]?

no validation rules with given error message. @prem22

@Vinay for account and contact, owd is private, object level modify all access, role hierarchy is not enabled.
